# Kubernets pod can resolve IP of another service (db) but Node JS app can not

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I have mysql server and Node JS app hosted on kubernetes as separate services.

I want to connect to the mysql server from the Node JS app.

Pod which hosts Node JS app can resolve the mysql service name to its IP address, but from the Node js app itself this is not possible.

Tried using node js built-in module dns with no success:

```
const dns = require('dns');
  
const dnsPromises = dns.promises;

const databaseHostname = 'mysql-svc';

try {
    const databaseIpAddress = await dnsPromises.resolve(databaseHostname);
catch (error) {
    console.log(`ERROR WHILE DNS RESOLVING HOSTNAME: ${databaseHostname}`);
}
```

Throws the following ENOTFOUND:

[dnsPromises.resolve error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovBaM.png)

Comment: are this services  on the same namespace ?

Comment: Yes, they are. @m303945